# Importing metadata between HTML files

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I currently have several html files that have the same meta data in the <head> and I was wondering if there was a way I could import that between files using a common header.html file so that I don't need to manually copy and paste each time.

I have tried several solutions, mainly involving using jQuery or importing the head file, but they all resolve in a 500 error.

For additional context, this is HTML with jQuery contained in a flask app, so the html is static, and solutions like using PHP files doesn't work.

The head file contains metadata, scripts, and links

Comment: It would be best to do this server side, for a variety of reasons, so the PHP solutions would be the most relevant - assuming your hosting provider supports PHP of course.

Comment: *solutions mentioning php..not relevant* - why are they not relevant? Are you using a different backend from php?  for example [tag:asp.net-mvc]?    Or are you using only static `.html` files with no back-end server?

Comment: Have you tried using `w3-include-html` and vanilla javascript as explained in attached link. Also if you are using any specific framework or build/compilation/transpiler tool then please specify it in question. 

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-include-another-html-file-in-an-html-file

Comment: we are using flask, so the html is static

Comment: @VivekTikar — w3- stuff is generally pretty bad, but any kind of client-side JS is a terrible choice here because many tools which consume metadata do not support it.

Comment: @njoshi - that really doesn’t follow. The whole point of Flask is that it isn’t static. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/templating/

Comment: Maybe I just failed to understand the framework. I will take a look into the templating and see if that solves my issue

Answer (score 2):

OP stated "those didn't seem to be relevant" -- "seem" being the operative word .. Which suggests that it's  OPs opinion that a server-side approach isn't relevant. If this is a physical restriction, then this answer is null. But I answered under the assumption that OP isn't yet educated on server side vs client side.

The PHP (server-side) method not only is relevant, it's THE way to do it (although ANY server side language would suffice).  You just create a file (here we'll call it `head.php`) and `include()` or `require()` it into your main file(s) -- here we'll call our sample main file `index.php`.

[PHP include()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
[PHP require()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

Inside `head.php` you can put whatever contents you want to serve globally across all files.

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...  Stuff
    </head>
```

And inside `index.php` you'll include `head.php` and then continue on with your "non standard" html for the page.

```
 <?php
    include('head.php');
 ?>
 <body>




 ....  Page content

 </body>
 </html>
```

The beauty of this, is that if you need to make a change to the `head` content, you make the change once and it affects all pages that have the file "included"

Keep in mind this isn't a "PHP only" solution.  Any server-side language can handle what we're attempting here.

[Server Side Explaination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Introduction)

[Server Side Language List](https://www.google.com/search?q=server+side+language+list)

Comment: I tried implementing the solution, like you said and now the application is returning a 500 error

Comment: Make sure the full path is in the `include('/var/www/path/to/file/head.php');` If All else fails look into [error reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)